# Two Step Keypress Event on MenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

I am making a Windows Form in C#.  I have a menustrip (File, Edit, Tools, etc.) with the following paths:
  -File->New->NewItem1
  -File->New->NewItem2
  -File->New->NewItem3

Anyway, I would like to add shortcut keys to each of these "NewItem"s.  I want them to be like some of the hotkeys in Visual Studio where you press a series of keys.
For example, to expand/unexpand, you press "Ctrl + M" and then while holding "Ctrl" you press "L"

So basically, I want the user to press "Ctrl + N", then release N, then press another key to indicate which "NewItem" is selected.

Thanks.

```
this.newToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = ((System.Windows.Forms.Keys)((System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control | System.Windows.Forms.Keys.N)));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I grab a double key stroke in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399532/how-can-i-grab-a-double-key-stroke-in-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive you can do that by storing the first shortcut in a class field and when the other shortcut is pressed you use them both.